# Mapping with values signifying set membership

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

I'm trying to achieve set membership functionality where keys are member IDs:

```
mapping(uint => mapping(uint => bool)) s;
s[0][1] = true;
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Expected identifier but got '='
```

I've also tried with a `uint` mapping to a `struct (with` a single `mapping` member), but got a similar result.

N.B.: Tested in Remix.

Comment: You may need to share your full code. Just a guess based on what you shared, but maybe your line of code `s[0][1] = true` is not inside a function.

Comment: @smarx, yes, that's correct.
Both of these lines are located prior to any function definitions.
My intention is to use constant mapping at the largest possible scope (but still only accessible within the contract).
Should the initialization be moved to the constructor instead?

Comment: Yes. You can't execute statements like that outside of a function.

Comment: Thanks, this does make sense!
Is there any way I can enforce `const`ness, though?

Comment: No, you'll just have to make sure you have no more assignments to members of the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to expand your sample to use functions and proper syntax.

Try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    mapping(uint => mapping(uint => bool)) s;

    constructor() public {
        s[0][1] = true;
    }

    function readUser(uint A, uint B)
    public
    view
    returns(bool)
    {
        return s[A][B];
    }
}
```

You can then compile it in remix and read back the user using the `readUser()` function.

Comment: My intention is to encode some "business logic" within the mapping.
It's meant to stay constant at all times. Should the assignments be moved to the contract constructor instead?

Comment: If your intention is to have `s[0][1] = true` one time, and always at the beginning, then yes, putting in the `constructor()` function should be just fine.

Comment: Updated my example

Comment: Thanks again!
Is there any way I can enforce `const`ness? Also, is there a better way to achieve a set membership functionality for this simple use case?

Comment: I think you will need to expand a bit more. [Constants are a thing in solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#constant-state-variables), but a mapping cannot be a constant. If you are trying to create a generalized "setter" function, but want to make sure to preserve `s[0][1]` to be `true`, then you could add that logic to the setter function. If you want to expand on your question, feel free to make a new post :)

Comment: Your expansion upon your answer is sufficient! :)